# Parsing nested arguments

Tags: shell-script, arguments

I am not able to parse the arguments of a script properly. The scenario is explained below.

First script (test2.sh):

```
#! /bin/sh
arg_part1="./test1.sh '123 789'"
arg_part2=456

#Option 1
${arg_part1} ${arg_part2} 

#Option 2
$("$arg_part1" arg_part2)
```

Second script (test1.sh):

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "Hello World $1 $2"
```

Output:

```
Hello World '123 789'
./test1.sh '123 789': No such file or directory
```

Desired output:

```
Hello World 123 789 456
```

The '123 789' should be processed as first argument and 456 should be my second argument. **Note:** I do not have the option of breaking up arg_part1 in two different variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're "stuck" needing to use `eval` here, so that arg_part1 is reinterpreted as a command string, which is then parsed into a command and arguments:

```
#! /bin/sh
arg_part1="./test1.sh '123 789'"
arg_part2=456
eval "${arg_part1}" "${arg_part2}"
```

Output:

```
Hello World 123 789 456
```

Debug output:

```
$ sh -x test2.sh
+ arg_part1='./test1.sh '\''123 789'\'''
+ arg_part2=456
+ eval './test1.sh '\''123 789'\''' 456
++ ./test1.sh '123 789' 456
Hello World 123 789 456
```

Note that since you've inner-quoted `'123 789'`, they appear as a single `$1` argument to test1.sh.

Comment: Even though you're using eval, the variables should still be quoted to prevent filename expansion: `eval "$arg_part1 $arg_part2"`

Answer (score 3):

You could keep using the split+glob operator (those unquoted `${arg_part1}` and `${arg_part2}`), but use a different separator for the split part (as some of the elements contain one of the default separators (space)). You'd also want to disable the glob part.

```
#! /bin/sh -
arg_part1='./test1.sh|123 789'
arg_part2=456

IFS='|'  # split unquoted expansions on | instead of default SPC+TAB+NL
set -o noglob # disable the glob part (not that it would have any effect
              # in this particular case).

$arg_part1 $arg_part2 # invoke split+glob

# or since you're not intending to split $arg_part2
$arg_part1 "$arg_part2"
```

To store code, functions are often more appropriate than variables:

```
arg_part1() { ./test1.sh '123 789' "$@"; }
arg_part2=456

arg_part1 "$arg_part2"
```

and you don't have to mess-up with the split+glob operator, or use the dangerous `eval`.